# Deleting item from arraylist with map entry

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Conversation>> sortedhashmap = null;
```

How can we delete an element from the `ArrayList` based on an Integer key?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use, `sortedhashmap.remove(int);`